# Getting SyncConfiguration on android wear

Tags: android, realm, wear-os

I'm trying to get a valid SyncConfiguration on my android wearable app.  I have mobile working fine, user signs in and can add to ROS.  When the user logs in, I send the user as a shared preference using https://github.com/denley/WearPrefs and user.toJson()

```
public static void setRealmSyncConfig(SyncUser user) {
        SyncConfiguration defaultConfig = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, REALM_URL)           
                .errorHandler(new SyncSession.ErrorHandler() {
                    public void onError(SyncSession session, ObjectServerError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, error.getMessage());
                    }
                })
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(defaultConfig);

    }
```

When I call this method, I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: User not authenticated
>   or authentication expired.

How can I get a valid user on wear without having to login on the wear app separately from the mobile app?  Should I be passing sync credentials and logging in again and how would I do that securely?

Using realm-java v3.7.2  and ROS v1.8.3

Comment: for now, you need to login again on the wearable side .

Comment: Thanks @beeender. Is there a way to send synccredentials to the wearable (i.e. can I use gson to transfer as a json string)?  Also, your comment says "for now"…  is there a fix for this being tracked somewhere?

Comment: we have an old issue tracking wearable issues: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2007 I have just updated it according your question.  "Is there a way to send synccredentials to the wearable" i think you need to stay with the way how does android transfer data to wearables normally. https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html

Comment: Got synccredentials working by passing tokens and email/password using datalayer api, but am now stuck with a SocketTimeoutException since this is pre-wear 2.0 and doesn't support standalone wifi.  I wanted to use ROS because I tried manually syncing the mobile/wear realms but it was a real pain.  Looks like this is also a dead-end.  Will monitor the realm issue, thanks for your help.

Comment: From https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/network-access.html , the wearable should be able to access network through the bluetooth connection to the phone. We haven't tested this, but in general, it should work i think?